# Get list of all instantiated controls in registry

Tags: sapui5

I understand that OpenUI5's has a registry of instantiated controls and can be queried with [`sap.ui.getCore().byId`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#byId).

But, is there a way to get a full list of instances in the control registry?

Something like this:

```
var aControls = sap.ui.getCore().allControls();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the commits [`54df6ca`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/54df6ca4a42824687939d6386f2d41f7831bc79d) and [`95445e2`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/95445e2883b71ee2bee5e233700f65cb2918aa12) included since UI5 1.67 and 1.120 respectively, no more workarounds are needed. The new static registry layer of `Element` and `Component` includes APIs such as `.all()`, `.filter()`, `.forEach()`, `.get()`, and `.size`. Take a look at each API reference:

#### [`sap/ui/core/ElementRegistry`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/core/ElementRegistry) (1.120) / [`Element.registry`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Element.registry) (1.67)

> Registry of all `sap.ui.core.Element`s that currently exist.

#### [`sap/ui/core/ComponentRegistry`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/core/ComponentRegistry) (1.120) / [`Component.registry`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Component.registry) (1.67)

> Registry of all `Component`s that currently exist.

### Sample

```js
sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/ElementRegistry", // since 1.120
], (ElementRegistry) => {
  const registeredStuff = ElementRegistry.all(); // or .filter(fn, this), .forEach(fn, this), .get("..."), .size
  console.log(registeredStuff);
});
```

[image: ui5 get registered elements]

If the application runs in UI5 below 1.67, keep reading for workarounds..

---

## ≤ UI5 1.66

> Is there a way to get a full list of instances in the control registry?

With a bit of cheating, yes!

### <del>Option 1 - via `.mElements` from the real core</del>

```js
getRegisteredElements: function() {
  let core;
  const fakePlugin = {
    startPlugin: realCore => core = realCore
  };
  // "Core" required from "sap/ui/core/Core"
  Core.registerPlugin(fakePlugin);
  Core.unregisterPlugin(fakePlugin);
  return core.mElements;
},
```

The API [`registerPlugin`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Core/methods/registerPlugin) awaits an object that contains a method `startPlugin` (and `stopPlugin`) as an argument. It [invokes the `startPlugin` method](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c071661cf039fe9a6cd9413ea9a05ccb808d95ba/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Core.js#L3421) immediately as long as the core is initialized. As a parameter, we're getting the real core from which we can get the map of all registered elements via `mElements`

[image: UI5 - get registered elements]

⚠️ `.mElements` is a private member. It has been removed in future UI5 releases!
⚠️ `Core.registerPlugin()` and `.unregisterPlugin()` are deprecated since 1.73.

### Option 2 - via `Core.byFieldGroupId` (controls only)

```js
getRegisteredControls: function() { // "Core" required from "sap/ui/core/Core"
  return Core.byFieldGroupId("" || []); // pass an empty string or an empty array!
},
```

This will return an array of all registered elements that are of type `sap.ui.core.Control` [(source)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/037c4c73d86c5c2718503cac2c84c3f55c3c7ab2/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Core.js#L3597-L3609). Passing `""` or `[]` ensures that all controls are returned, **regardless** whether the control has a field group ID or not.

### Option 3 - via Opa Plugin (for tests)

When writing tests, another option is to use the dedicated public API [`getAllControls`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.test.OpaPlugin/methods/getAllControls) from `sap.ui.test.OpaPlugin`:

```js
new OpaPlugin().getAllControls(); // "OpaPlugin" required from "sap/ui/test/OpaPlugin"
```

Although the name suggests it will return *Controls*, it actually returns Element instances as well.
The plugin provides some other interesting APIs too, such as [`getMatchingControls`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.test.OpaPlugin/methods/getMatchingControls) (with options to provide `controlType?`, `visible?`, `interactable?`, etc..) which might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the update regarding 1.67+, could you, please, provide some code snippet for `sap.ui.core.Element.registry.filter(callback, thisArg?)`? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeB. Here is an example: visit https://ui5.sap.com and enter `sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/Element"], El => console.log(El.registry.filter(el => el.isA("sap.m.Button"))));` in the console. The browser will log all instances that are of type `sap.m.Button`. Functions like `.filter` are called _[higher order functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99)_. As an argument, you just need to pass a function that returns a boolean value. That function will than be called for every element in the registry.

Comment: thanks for the code sample. It works for me, but now I want not just get the elements, but also update their values. But it looks like that `filter` returns a _new_ array. Is there a way to iterate and update the values of multiple `sap.m.Input` items? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeB. What is the actual intent? Would be nice if you could open a new question with more details so that more people can help with better answers

Comment: I've opened a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920185, I can reset the input fields, but I'm not sure regarding the performance point of view.

Answer (score 1):

There is no currently documented way of obtaining the complete list of elements. The elements are registered in the `mElements` private map (object) inside the core instance. You can check this object's usages inside the [Core source code](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Core.js). It is never exposed directly to the outside world via a method.

Normally, you would be able to simply go around the 'private' access level which is just a convention in JavaScript and just do `sap.ui.getCore().mElements`, but this will not work in this case. This is because the core is wrapped into an [Interface](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.Interface.html) (through a closure) which only holds proxies to the public methods. This implies that you have no way of getting the real core instance from the `sap.ui.getCore()` call, so you cannot access the `mElements` property from there.

I don't know any way of obtaining the 'raw' core instance (and normally it should not be possible - the guys at SAP intended to do defensive programming here and not allow users to meddle with the core internals). If you would manage to obtain it through some way, then you could access this 'private' property and obtain the element list (actually, a map between ID and reference).

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for this.

If your page has a  root view you could create a recuresive function that traverse the view tree by applying getters for each control aggregations and going over all they content (and so on).

You can use the control's `getMetadata()` method for getting the public aggregations names.

Note that in this way you only have access to controls on the public aggregations and not to inner ones.