# Get All Elements of Certain Type on a Website

Tags: sapui5

I need to find all Input elements (`sap.m.Input`) on a website. 
I know I can find an element by its ID via `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` but this does not help me here.

I am looking for something like `sap.ui.getCore().getByType("sap.m.Input")`. How do I do this?

Edit: I do not have access to the source code of the website, I am injecting a javascript via a chrome extension on websites which use SAPUI5

Comment: By "website" do you mean **all** the Input controls that were created during the lifecycle of the app? Or just those in the page the user is currently viewing?

Comment: Your second guess is correct, I just need those in the page the user is currently viewing.

Comment: Now the last edit changes everything :P Not sure if my answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### From the current page

```xml
<mvc:View ...>
  <Input fieldGroupIds="myInputs" />
</mvc:View>
```

```js
// In the Controller
this.getView().getControlsByFieldGroupId("myInputs").filter(c => c.isA("sap.m.Input"));
```

### From the whole app

Leveraging [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227512/5846045) in [Get list of all instantiated controls in registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44370221/5846045):

```js
const allRegisteredControls = sap.ui.getCore().byFieldGroupId(""); // From https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227512/5846045
const inputControls = allRegisteredControls.filter(c => c.isA("sap.m.Input"));
```

<sup>[API reference: `sap.ui.base.Object#isA`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.Object/methods/isA)</sup>

This returns all registered instances of the given type. Please not that already destroyed elements won't be included.

Comment: I do not have access to the source code of the website, therefore I can't add custom fieldGroupIds to every Input. I do like your second solution but could you clarify what "For the whole app" means here?

Comment: @KonstantinDobler By "app" I mean the UI5 web app the user is currently using. I used the term _app_ to indicate that the second solution is to retrieve **all** the controls (in our case, instances of `sap.m.Input`) that have been created, and not yet destroyed, since the start of the web app. Since UI5 apps usually consist of multiple views/pages, you might get false positives that were created at some point but not included at the current view/page user is viewing.

Comment: I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626590/10917436) to check whether a given control is currently visible to the user. Using this I would be able to modify the "For the whole App" solution to only include controls on the current page.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

I get all elements of the class `sap.m.Input` from the DOM-Tree with 
 document.getElementsByClassName("sap.m.Input")`.

I then get the corresponding UI5-Elements by calling `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` on the ID of each element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to set each Input field to a specific Field Group like this

```
<input fieldGroupIds="MyGroup" />
```

and then get all those fields using the [byFieldGroupId](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core/methods/byFieldGroupId) method like this

```
var aMyGroupControls = sap.ui.getCore().byFieldGroupId("MyGroup");
```

aMyGroupControls will be filled with an Array of Controls